# Multiple d3 charts on a page using the same Angular2 component

Tags: angular, d3.js

I have a horizontal bar chart component that takes a data @Input which will then be used by a chart library `horizontalBarChart`:

```
export class HorizontalBarChartComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() data: Object[];
  ngOnInit() {
    horizontalBarChart.init({
      id: '#horizontal-bar-chart',
      data: this.data
    });
  }
}
```

Inside `horizontal-bar-chart.html`:

```
<div id="horizontal-bar-chart"></div>
```

And `d3` selects for the given id in the chart library:

```
 const svg = d3.select(chartOptions.id)
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom);
```

Now I would like to generate multiple bar chart, each with different data, in a component page:

```
      <div>
        <h6>Group</h6>
        <app-horizontal-bar-chart [data]="data.chart1"</app-horizontal-bar-chart>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h6>Ctp</h6>
        <app-horizontal-bar-chart [data]="data.chart2"</app-horizontal-bar-chart>
      </div>
```

The issue is both charts are generated inside the `<div id="horizontal-bar-chart"></div>` of the FIRST component.

What is the best way to solve this kinda scenario?

**EDIT:**

The way I currently solve this problem is to give each of the chart component a `div` placeholder:

```
          <div>
            <h6>Group</h6>
            <div id="chart1"></div>  // placeholder
            <app-horizontal-bar-chart [id]="chart1" [data]="data.chart1"</app-horizontal-bar-chart>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h6>Ctp</h6>
            <div id="chart2"></div>  // placeholder
            <app-horizontal-bar-chart [id]="chart2"[data]="data.chart2"</app-horizontal-bar-chart>
          </div>
```

However I'm wondering if there is more of a Angular2 way of solving this, probably using `ViewContainerRef` or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the idea is just to create a reusable d3-chart component, you don't need an Id. I'd implemented it in the following way:

Chart component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'bar-chart',
  template: `
    <svg width="300" height="200"></svg>
  `,
})
export class BarChart implements OnInit {
  @Input() data: Array<any>;

  constructor(private container: ElementRef) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.initSvg();
    this.initAxis();
    this.drawAxis();
    this.drawBars();
  }

  private initSvg() {
    // This is how you can select the svg tag
    // related to the current cumponent
    this.svg = d3.select(this.container.nativeElement).select("svg");
    ...
  }

  ...
}
```

Chart consumer component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <bar-chart [data]="dataset1"></bar-chart>
    <bar-chart [data]="dataset2"></bar-chart>
  `,
})
export class App {
  dataset1 = [ ... ];
  dataset2 = [ ... ];
}
```

Here is the **[Plunkr](https://embed.plnkr.co/7bdo4bVi80hCVthNHyDB/)**

Comment: could you please create a jsfiddle of this issue?

Comment: I changed my answer slightly. Here is the [Plunkr](https://embed.plnkr.co/7bdo4bVi80hCVthNHyDB/)

Comment: this is a much better solution!

Comment: thanks, this helped resolve my issue. When trying to display two different charts using two instances of same component, they were overlapping. This approach helped to separate the two instances.